# Prettyphoto photo link lightbox not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, lightbox, prettyphoto

The photos are turning into lightbox links on the gallery page itself, but on the page:

[www.rimibasu.com/kriyacollective](http://www.rimibasu.com/kriyacollective)

they photos are not clickable links. If anyone has a clue, please advise or tell me what I need to send further. I am a noob at this stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may first want to make sure you have called the prettyPhoto script and style sheet in your head tag

```
<script type="javascript" src="prettyPhoto/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="prettyPhoto/css/prettyPhoto.css" />
```

then be sure to include the following after your  tag containing your link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto(
                {
                   deeplinking: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```